# Codeigniter CIBonfire how to change mode from development to production?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, bonfire

I'm creating my first app using [CIBonfire](http://cibonfire.com) and i'm ready to push it to production, but i'm not sure how to change the mode from development to production so that it does not show the profiler stuff in the footer.

I was not able to find it in any of the settings menus or in the documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a bit odd but, `$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);` ?

Comment: I think its in the `index.php` file

Comment: ye, `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` in index.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `index.php` file in your CI-Bonfire. you can find this spot here, just change the `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')` into `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production')`

```
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```